# java code that i am unable to rectify

Tags: java

I wrote this java code for a project I am working on. I have gone as far as I can, but still can't get it to work, so I thought I would try here.

The program is supposed to use a `JOptionPane` to ask the user what to city's he would like to see the mileage distance between. Those numbers come from a .txt file.

I always get an error that "j" cant be found.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Mileage
{
    public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    throws IOException
    {
        String str3 = "";

        Scanner localScanner = new Scanner(new File(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the data file.")));

        String str1 = localScanner.nextLine() + " Cities:\n\n";

        int i = localScanner.nextInt();

        ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList(i);

        int[][] arrayOfInt = new int[i][i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            localScanner.nextLine();
            localArrayList.add(localScanner.nextLine());
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) 
            {

                arrayOfInt[j][k] = localScanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        j = 1 ;
        for (String str4 : localArrayList)
        {
            str1 = str1 + j++ + ". " + str4 + "\n"; str1 = str1 + "\nEnter from and to cities for mileage, \"Quit\" or \"quit\" to quit.";
            String str2;
        }
        do 
        {
            str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(str3 + str1);
            if (str2.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            localScanner = new Scanner(str2);
            int m = localScanner.nextInt();
            int n = localScanner.nextInt();
            if ((m < 1) || (m > i) || (n < 1) || (n > i))
                str3 = "Invalid values, try again.\n\n";
            else {
                str3 = "The distance between " + (String)localArrayList.get(m - 1) + " and " + (String)localArrayList.get(n - 1) + " is " + arrayOfInt[(m - 1)][(n - 1)] + " miles.\n\n";
            }
        }

        while (!str2.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
    }
}
```

and here is another form I tried, little is different, but both have same error:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MileageTest
{
    public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    throws IOException
    {
        String str5 = "";

        String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the data file.");
        Scanner localScanner = new Scanner(new File(str1));

        String str2 = localScanner.nextLine();

        int i = localScanner.nextInt();

        ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList(i);

        int[][] arrayOfInt = new int[i][i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            localScanner.nextLine();
            localArrayList.add(localScanner.nextLine());
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) 
            {
                arrayOfInt[j][k] = localScanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        String str3 = str2 + " Cities:\n\n";
        j = 1;
        for (String str6 : localArrayList)
            str3 = str3 + j++ + ". " + str6 + "\n"; 
            str3 = str3 + "\nEnter from and to cities for mileage, \"Quit\" or \"quit\" to quit.";
            String str4;
        do {
            str4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(str5 + str3);
            if (str4.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                continue;
            localScanner = new Scanner(str4);
            int m = localScanner.nextInt();
            int n = localScanner.nextInt();
            if ((m < 1) || (m > i) || (n < 1) || (n > i))
                str5 = "Invalid values, try again.\n\n";
            else 
            {
                str5 = "The distance between " + (String)localArrayList.get(m - 1) + " and " + (String)localArrayList.get(n - 1) + " is " + arrayOfInt[(m - 1)][(n - 1)] + " miles.\n\n";
            }
        }

        while (!str4.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
        test();
    }

   private static void test()
   {
        System.out.println("Testing...");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        localScanner.nextLine();
        localArrayList.add(localScanner.nextLine());
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) 
        {

            arrayOfInt[j][k] = localScanner.nextInt();
        }
    }
    j = 1 ; <--- THIS IS THE PROBLEM. j does not exist at this scope.
```

Comment: ok, i moved it to the stated location. i guess that makes sense, but now it gives me an error in the for (int j=0; j<i; j++) part. it says j is already defined in the main method.

would you say that other than that error this code is good for what i am trying to do? or should i through it away and start something els?

i just cant seem to get this to work right.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In both versions of your code you're declaring the variable `j` in your `for` statement:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

When you declare `j` this way, it's scope is limited to the `for` loop, and it isn't usable outside the loop. But you're trying to use it outside the loop.

If you want to continue to use `j` after that `for` loop, declare it outside the loop:

```
int j = 0;
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, the j variable is declared inside the for loop which means it is local to the for loop. It is not visible from the outside. Just declare it before the for loop:

```
int j = 0;
```

and then

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

The above is true for the second piece of code, too.